# Password and username recover

Tags: password-recovery

I recently bought a IBM Thinkpad with Ubuntu. I do not know the password.

I tried to change it by using the recovery method but when I'm prompted to enter the new password I can't enter anything because the keyboard doesn't respond. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the keyboard isn't responding? For some password prompts, nothing will appear when you type. Try to just type the password you want to change it to and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from [the Community Lost Password document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword)